# SQL possible subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

all the day I'm thinking how to get the result with a single query from a single table. I ask you, if I can get the desired result, as in the exampe I have attached.

```
            campo1  campo2  campo3  
              A       A1      10    
              A       A1      20    
              A       A2      5 
              B       B1      50    
              B       B2      60    
              C       C1      80    
              C       C2      90    
              C       C2     100    


I want to get                   
SUM of campo3 GROUPED BY campo1                 
SUM of campo3 GROUPED BY campo2     
in this case I want to get this result;
A= 35
B= 110
C= 270
A1=30
A2=5
B1=50
B2=60
C1=80
C2=190
```

Comment: what should the output look like?

Comment: And what prevents you from assembling a `SELECT` clause, a `FROM` clause, and a `GROUP BY` clause that together form a query that yields such a result?  This is neither a tutorial site nor a code-writing service.

Comment: can not get the result with a single query. The sum of a field can not help add another. Just wondering if there is a way to get the result with a single query.

Comment: A UNION ALL with a NULL campo2 in the select statement that does not group by campo1 and campo2 would work here. If you want only two columns instead of three then alternate group by campo1 and campo2 in the union statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
Select Campo1,null, Sum(Campo3) From Table
Group By Campo1
Union All
Select null, Campo2, Sum(Campo3) From Table
Group By Campo2
```